# Convert a dataframe in list format to matrix format in R

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix

I have the following data.frame in R.

```
(df1 <- data.frame(col1=rep(c('a','b','c'),each=3),
                   col2=rep(c('d','e','f'),3),
                   col3=1:9))

  col1 col2 col3
1    a    d    1
2    a    e    2
3    a    f    3
4    b    d    4
5    b    e    5
6    b    f    6
7    c    d    7
8    c    e    8
9    c    f    9
```

And I want to transform it into the following format.

```
  d e f
a 1 2 3
b 4 5 6
c 7 8 9
```

What's the easiest way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is `xtabs`

```
xtabs(col3~ col1 + col2, df1)
```

---

Or using `acast`

```
reshape2::acast(df1, col1 ~ col2)
```

Comment: Thank you, but how do I convert it from xtabs to a data.frame or matrix class?

Comment: @Rodrigo If you want a data.frame wrap with `as.data.frame.matrix` and the `acast` output is a `matrix`.  `xtabs` is also a `matrix` with `xtabs` attribute which we can remove it if needed

Comment: e.g. if `out <- xtabs(col3 ~ col1 + col2, df1); class(out) <- "matrix"; attr(out, "call") <- NULL; names(dimnames(out)) <- NULL` or convert to sparse and then reconvert to `matrix` i.e. `out <- xtabs(col3 ~ col1 + col2, df1, sparse = TRUE); as.matrix(out)`

Comment: Awesome! Thank you for another lesson.